# Creating generic templates and using it XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XSL :

```
    <xsl:template match="ImageView" >
    <view id ="3" src="{@src}" >
      <xsl:element name="form">
         <xsl:value-of select="@form"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </view>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TextView" >
    <view id ="5" src="{@src}" >
      <xsl:element name="form">
         <xsl:value-of select="@form"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </view>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to know If I can use generic templates in my case? If yes, how can I use it? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

My XML:

```
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/3"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"
                custom:form="SOME_VALUE" />

                 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/5"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"
                custom:form="SOME_VALUE" />
```

My expected result should be something like this:

```
    <ImageView >
     <view id="3" src="@drawable/icon">
        <form> SOME_VALUE</form>
     </view>
       </ImageView>
```

Same applies for `<TextView>` as well. I will be using the same `src` and `custom:form` values. Only `id` will be different.

Comment: The `id` attribute isn't allowed on `xsl:template`, what exactly are you trying to achieve here?  Can you give an example of your input XML and desired output?

Comment: Could you please tell me why is "id" not valid in the xsl:template???

Comment: Because the XSLT specification says so ([v1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Defining-Template-Rules), [v2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#defining-templates)).  Again, what do you actually want to achieve with these templates?  What significance did you expect that `id` attribute to have?

Comment: I have made some changes in the question.

Comment: Can you explain the rules you want for getting the attribute values? That is to say, how do you get from `@+id/3` to just `3`, and how do you get from `@drawable/icon` to `A`? It also looks like you are trying to remove the namespace prefixes too? Perhaps it would help if you showed a bit more of your XML? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for putting the question wrong..I have made more changes in my code...Actually at the moment I am hardcoding "id" value (which is not the main concern)...But what I want to know now is can I use these 2 templates with only a single one?? If yes, How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify your attribute namespaces.

You can also use the `xsl:copy` instruction to copy the current element, and hence have one generic template for both views.

And then I've used the `substring-after` function to get the value for the @id attribute.

Hopefully this gets you on the correct path.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:android="http://android"   
        xmlns:custom="http://custom" exclude-result-prefixes="android custom">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="ImageView|TextView">
        <xsl:copy>
            <view id="{substring-after(@android:id, '/')}" src="{@android:src}">
                <form><xsl:value-of select="@custom:form"/></form>
            </view>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks..The `id` part is working well..But after using `@android:src` and `@custom:form` I do not get any values..I have added the prefixes `xmlns:android` and `xmlns:custom`.

Comment: I don't understand how `@android:id` can have worked, and `@android:src` not work. please ensure your namespaces match exactly (not the prefix, but the entire URI part).

Comment: the `@android:id` is hardcoded(which is not the main concern)..but others are not..and the URL seems to be correct..

Comment: If you are using a version 2.0 XSLT processor you can do `@*:src`, or in version 1.0 you could try `@*[local-name()='src']`.